# Lost my JKS but have the keystore and keystore password

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, apk, keystore

I am attempting to generate a signed APK to deploy on my device (To further test) and my developer went on vacation for a few weeks.

He gave me a .dms and .keystore file, as well as the keystore passwords and alias.
I am getting an error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file '<location_here>' not found for signing config 'externalOverride'.
```

After some research on Stack Overflow it seemed like I might be missing my .jks file and this is needed perhaps to move past this.

If this is true, is there a way to generate a the JKS somehow based on the fact I have the .dms and .keystore and passwords?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need can use either a .jks OR a .keystore to sign, so it was purely my misunderstanding.